# How to set ngx modal to the middle of the screen?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

How to set ngx modal to the center of the screen? By default, it is almost on top,
class: 'modal-dialog-centered', on the parameters doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `.modal` class in a ModalComponent of ngx-bootstrap, so, you can try to override its styles and position your modal, as you want

It basically looks like this :

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```